# Passing local variable into partial returns NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, renderpartial, partials

I am trying to pass the index of something into a partial and am getting a NameError.

Right now, this is my render statement and I am able to access builder just fine.

```
<%= render 'my_partial', :builder => form_helper %>
```

But when adding index like below, I get the error.

```
<%= render 'my_partial', :builder => form_helper, :locals => {:index => index } %>
```

Any thoughts? 
Thanks!

edit:

While trying

```
<%= render :partial => 'my_partial', :locals => {:builder => form_helper, :index => index } %>
```

The specific error is "undefined local variable or method `index' for #<#:0x007fc37206ae40>"

Comment: does the error really occur in the partial?

Comment: Is `index` defined in the view that's passing it to the partial? Maybe it's `@index`.

Answer (score 2):

Either:

```
 <%= render 'my_partial', :builder => form_helper, :index => index %>
```

Or:

```
<%= render :partial => 'my_partial', :locals => {:index => index, :builder => form_helper } %>
```

Comment: And then I should be able to access index by just writing '<%= index %>' in my partial?

Comment: From the [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#partial-layouts): "Also note that explicitly specifying `:partial` is required when passing additional options such as `:layout`." Same applies when passing `:locals`

Comment: I am trying the second option in apneadiving's post above and while builder still works correctly, it still says  undefined local variable or method 'index'. Does it matter that index is just an integer?

Comment: @apneadiving I know, I just wanted to add a reference to the documentation.

Comment: Added the wording back in my original description!

Comment: **ALSO: Would it make a difference that it's technically passing from one partial to another?